# Injectivity of the function $i\sqrt{2}\sin{z/2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $U=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|Re(z)|<\pi\}$. Then why is the function $f:U\rightarrow f(U), f(z)=i\sqrt{2}\sin{z/2}$ injective and is there a way to describe $f(U)$?

Comment: Hint:

$$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

Comment: Hi, yes I know that but how does this solve my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight-forward calculation shows that
$$
 \frac{\left( \dfrac{w+i}{w-i} \right)^2 + 1}{\left( \dfrac{w+i}{w-i} \right)^2 - 1} = \frac{1}{2i} \bigl( w - \frac 1w \bigr ) \, .
$$
With $w = e^{i z/2}$ it follows that 
$$
 \sin \frac z2 = \frac{\left( \dfrac{e^{i z/2}+i}{e^{i z/2}-i} \right)^2 + 1}{\left( \dfrac{e^{i z/2}+i}{e^{i z/2}-i} \right)^2 - 1}
$$
which is a composition of the mappings
$$
 z \to e^{i z/2}, z \to \frac{z+i}{z-i}, z \to z^2, z \to \frac{z+1}{z-1}
$$
Now you can investigate the injectivity and compute the image in four steps:

- Show that $z \to e^{i z/2}$ is injective in  $U$ and maps $U$ to the right halfplane.
- Show that $z \to \frac{z+i}{z-i}$ is a bijective mapping of  the right halfplane to the upper halfplane.
- Show that $z \to z^2$ is a bijective mapping of the upper halfplane
  to $\Bbb C \setminus [0, \infty)$.
- Show that $z \to \frac{z+1}{z-1}$ is a bijective mapping of 
  $\Bbb C \setminus [0, \infty)$ to 
  $\Bbb C  \setminus ((-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty))$.

Finally multiply by $i \sqrt 2$.

In the second and fourth step you can use that Möbius transformations
are bijective mappings of the extended complex plane onto itself,
and map lines or circles to lines or circles.

Comment: What a nice idea! To the first step: The image in the first step is $\{Re(z)>0\}$, I agree. But what is the image in the second step? I know that $(z-i)/(z+i)$ maps the upper half plane to the unit disk. Does this help?

Comment: @N.Sch:  You need the image of the right half plane under $(z-i)/(z+i)$. The image must be a disk or half plane. $z=-i$ is mapped to $\infty$, therefore the image is not a disk. Now map some other points to see what the imaginary axis is mapped to ...

Comment: Why under $(z-i)/(z+i)$ and not $(z+i)/(z-i)$?

Comment: @N.Sch: My fault. I copied the expression from your last comment, but you are right, what you need is the mapping of $(z+i)/(z-i)$. But the same method applies. Map e.g. $z=0, i, -i, \infty$ to see what the imaginary axis is mapped to. Then map $z=1$ to choose between two half planes.

Comment: I get the upper half plane. So in the third step I get the set $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$. And in the fourth?

Comment: @N.Sch: Correct so far. Now what is the mapping of $[0, \infty)$ under $z \to (z+1)/(z-1)$ ? Then take the complement.

Comment: This is $(-\infty,0]$. So the answer is $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. Since we have to multiply with $i\sqrt{2}$ we get $\mathbb{C}\setminus i(-\infty,0]$

Comment: @N.Sch: No, that is not correct (note that $z=1$ is mapped to $\infty$). I have updated the answer with more details.

Comment: okay, I got it. What is the set $i \sqrt{2} \Bbb C  \setminus ((-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty))$?

Comment: @N.Sch Multiplying with $i$ is a rotation. Multiplying with a real constant is ... ?

Comment: $\Bbb C  \setminus ((-i\infty, -\sqrt{2}i] \cup [\sqrt{2}i, i\infty)) $?

Comment: @N.Sch You got it!

Comment: haha :D What would be the problem if we take $U=\{|Re(z)|< 2\pi\}$ for example?

Comment: @N.Sch: Then $z \to e^{i z/2}$ would map $U$ to $\Bbb C$ without the negative real axis, and $z \to z^2$ in step 3 were no longer injective.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

we may write

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(e^{iz/2}-e^{-iz/2}\right)$$

Suppose there's some $z \in U$ and $s \in \mathbb{C}$ with $z+2s \in U$ and $f(z)=f(z+2s)$. Notice the first condition implies $\left| \Re(s) \right|<\pi$, so $s \in U$ too. Then:

\begin{aligned} &e^{iz/2}e^{is}-e^{-iz/2}e^{-is}=e^{iz/2}-e^{-iz/2}\\
\Rightarrow\,\,  &e^{iz/2}\left(e^{is}-1\right)=e^{-iz/2}\left(e^{-is}-1\right) \end{aligned}

The terms in parantheses are all nonzero unless $s=2k\pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Because $s \in U$, this would imply $s=0$ and we'd have nothing to prove. Suppose hence that $s\neq 0$. Then:

\begin{aligned} \Rightarrow\,\,  &e^{iz}=\frac{e^{-is}-1}{e^{is}-1}=-e^{-is}=e^{-i(s+\pi)} \end{aligned}

It follows that $z=-(s+\pi)+2k\pi$, or $z+s=(2k-1)\pi$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $z, s \in U$, the signs of $\Re(z)$, $\Re(s)$ and $(2k-1)\pi$ must all be the same. We conclude that $\left|\Re(z+2s)\right|>\pi$, which contradicts $z+2s \in U$.

Since our assumption that $s\neq 0$ led to a contradiction, we must have $s=0$, that is, $f$ is injective on $U$.

Do you think you can take it from here and describe $f(U)$?